# Set toolbar to FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

There are similar lots of questions which I obviously tried but didn't help.

Followed by the Splash screen my app shows an activity with `viewPager`. I called this activity `FragmentContainer` because it contains the viewPager. Now just because this `FragmentContainer` extends `FragmentAcitity` I cannot use `setSupportActionBar()` to set my custom toolbar.

**fragment_container.xml** is something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_top_fc"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColorPrimary="@android:color/white"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:pstsPaddingMiddle="true"
        app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="24dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FragmentContanier.java**

```
public class FragmentContainer extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        //Tabs
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new FragmentEdit();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new FragmentMain();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new FragmentSavedMessages();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        CharSequence title = null;
        if (0 == position) {
            title = "Edit";
        } else if (1 == position) {
            title = "Main";
        } else if (2 == position) {
            title = "Save";
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

**I need help implementing a custom actionBar to this. Please guise.**

*Any help will be appreciated.*
*Feel free to suggest edits.*

Comment: Why don't you extend ```AppCompatActivity```  (support.v7) ? Also, you don't need to call ```setSupportActionBar```, you can implement a standalone actionbar. There are two ways to add an actionbar to your activities.

Comment: @danypata while learning to implement viewPager I was told to extend FragmentActivity in order to implement viewPager. After reading your comment I tried AppCompatActivity and thats working as well. Im still new so dont have too much command over it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a separate toolbar for a fragment. But you can customise the parent activity toolbar according to your fragment, set in onCreateView of fragment `sethasoptionsmenu(true);` and inflate your custom menu Items in

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
      Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_itemdetail, menu);
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me spot my parent activity. Because here I have just FragmentContainer and it cant have a toolbar

Comment: yea, but first for this, inflate a layout, like said by danypata, either by extending AppCompactActivity and setting a setSupportActionBar or by adding in Xml (which is a way too). and then if u want to inflate diffrent menu item for ur fragments , use the above code.

Comment: I added a toolbar in my xml. I changed to AppCompactActivity and set it via `setSupportActionBar()`. It is working. But I am not able to see the menu if I add your code. I inflated a common menu for all the fragments in `FragmentContainer` and it worked. Individual for each fragment is not working.

Comment: You want it that way, right? like custom(different) menu items for different fragments or u want the same menu for all fragments?

Comment: I **got** common menu for different fragments. I **want** different menu for diff fragments

Comment: Try following this link : http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/